# Visual Code intellisense breaks because OpenSSL includes safestack.h but file is named safestack.h.in

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, openssl, header

I've git-cloned the Openssl repository and opened it as a project within Visual Code. I'm having problems because intellisense cannot find some headers.

For example, the file `openssl/include/openssl/types.h` contains this error:

[image]

The reason is because within the repository `openssl/safestack.h` is actually named `openssl/safestack.h.in`:

[image]

This problem occurs for other headers.

Presumably the compiler is able to interpret this difference, so is it possible to fix the intellisense too?

Comment: `openssl/safestack.h.in` is not a C source file. Its called different because _it is something different_. Please read the __How to build__ section in their readme. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: `.in` files are often files that are modified by the build-process to form the resulting file without `.in`. If you have a `safestack.h.in` file, but not `safestack.h`, then that means you're trying to use the library without configuration or building.

Comment: You need to configure the project first. Look at `configure` script. You need to run it first. BTW IMO configuring VSC to build it will be not an easy job.

Comment: @0___________ Don't need VC to build it, just have the intellisense work. Or are they effectively the same thing here?

Comment: "Don't need VC to build it, just have the intellisense work" Why do you care about Intellisense for source files you don't want to compile?

Comment: Intellisense is just a tool of your IDE, and such tools commonly work only after some certain stage of the development process. For your issue it is necessary to _configure_ the project, you don't need to build it.